# Is there any good known solution for a fast persistent cache?

Tags: java, caching, persistent

I need really fast and persistent cache for my web crawler. It doesnt need to be as fast as ConcurrentSkipListSet in Java, but definitely it cannot be MySQL with hash-index based table, which i tried. After 1m+ of records it takes like 80% of processor time.

Does any one know or heard of something useful for this case?
Thanks for any hint.

Comment: the ConcurrentSkipListSet of course can stay in the game as level 1, what im looking for is something for level 2

Comment: How about Cassandra? Many properties would fit my scenario. Is it fast?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [EhCache](http://ehcache.org/). It's a primarily in-memory cache with options for overflow and persistence to disk backing store.  Been around for years, still actively developed, and very mature.

Comment: thanks, ill give it a try, pitty the BigMemory isn't free

Comment: I started looking at EHCache recently, I guess that BigMemory is not persistent.

Comment: i guess so too, but it preserves GC with off-heap storage which is fine, jvm can stay small so GC runs faster

Answer (score 3):

I am working on [cache2k](http://cache2k.org), and researching recent cache eviction policies to make it the fastest java cache around, see [cache2k benchmarks](http://cache2k.org/benchmarks.html).

Persistence is added right now and will be available for preview and testing in two weeks. I expect it to be very stable in five weeks. The cache2k implementation is, of course, not as mature as EHCache, however, everything released, is used in within our own applications and proves itself in production environments.

Update: The "two weeks" was very optimistic, since the whole locking concept needed finally a rewrite and careful inspection... You can track the persistence support currently emerging on [github](http://github.com/headissue/cache2k)

Comment: Is this now persistant cache? I have read the docs but can't any find any word in there?